# Is it possible to export module inside a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

So I just watched some tutorials on Youtube it's about uploading a file with [Multer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Qzmri1WaaE&t=1841s).

I need to export the variable gfs when it's connected to my `/routes` folder, but how can I do that?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream")

// Routes
const user = require("./routes/api/users")

// Init gfs
let gfs

// create gfs on connection 'open'
mongoose.connection
  .once("open", () => {
    // Init stream
    gfs = Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongoose.mongo)
    gfs.collection("uploads")
    console.log("mongoDB connected and gfs has been created")
  })
  .on("error", err => {
    console.log("connection error", err)
  })

// I need the gfs on the user routes
// use routes
app.use("/api/users", user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to access `gfs` inside your `middleware` and/or `controller`, you could do the following:

```js
mongoose.connection
  .once('open', () => {
    const gfs = Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongoose.mongo)
    gfs.collection('uploads')
    
    // use `app.locals` to store the result when it finishes
    app.locals.gfs = gfs
  })
```

According to the `Express` documentation:

> The `app.locals` object has properties that are local variables within the application.
>
> Once set, the value of `app.locals` properties persist throughout the life of the application, in contrast with `res.locals` properties that are valid only for the lifetime of the request.

---

It's important to remember, however, that inside of your `middleware` and/or `controller`, where your `route`s are being handled, you need to check if `gfs` exists before you do something with it.

The above call is asynchronous, so `gfs` won't be immediately available for you to use:

```js
app.use('api/users/', user)

// routes/api/users.js
route.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.app.locals.gfs) {
    // check if `app.locals.gfs` exists
  }
  // handle a case where `app.locals.gfs` hasn't been set yet
})
```

If you'd like to learn more about `app.locals`, here's a link:

- [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.locals)

Answer (score 0):

```
let conn = mongoose.createConnection(<url>);
let gfs = Grid(conn.db, conn.mongo);
gfs.collection("uploads");
// write routes
module.exports = gfs;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Comment: It didn't work, maybe because the gfs should be exported when it's connected

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.